# what is entity when create an order using REST api

Tags: magento2, api, sales-order

I am trying to create order using REST API I have got an error message **ordered: {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"entity"}}"**

What is ***entity*** field in order of magento2?.

**Api.php**

```
<?php
class MagentoClient {
  public $bearer_token = '';
  public $base_url = '';

  public function __construct($token, $base_url) {
    $this->base_url = $base_url;
    $this->bearer_token = $token;
  }


  public function request($endpoint, $method = 'GET', $body = FALSE) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->base_url . $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

      $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->bearer_token;
    if ($body) {
      $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
  }

  public function getProduct($product_id) {
    return $this->request('/products/' . $product_id . '/', 'GET');
  }

  public function createCart() {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/', 'POST');
  }

  public function addToCart($cart_id, $product_sku, $quantity = 1) {
    $order = array(
      'cartItem' => array(
        'quote_id' => $cart_id,
        'sku' => $product_sku,
        'qty' => $quantity,
      )
    );
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/items',
      'POST',
      json_encode($order)
      );
  }

  public function setShipping($cart_id, $shipping) {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/shipping-information',
      'POST',
      json_encode($shipping)
    );
  }

  public function placeOrder($cart_id, $payment_method = 'cashondelivery') {
    $payment = array(
      'paymentMethod' => array('method' => $payment_method)
    );

    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/order',
      'PUT',
      json_encode($payment)
    );
  }

  public function getPaymentMethods($cart_id) {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/payment-information', 'GET');
  }

}
```

**place-order.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'api.php';

// The URL to your Magento 2 instance (ending with /index.php/rest/V1)
$api_url = 'http://192.168.1.100/magento24/index.php/rest/V1/orders';
// Set the integrations access token.
$token = '00qlti27cwtsj2inmjg9w02yve991kib';
// Fill in the SKU of the product which should be ordered.
$sku = 'car';

$magento = new MagentoClient($token, $api_url);

$product = $magento->getProduct($sku);
$cart = $magento->createCart();
$cart = str_replace('"', '', $cart);

$order_filled = $magento->addToCart($cart, $sku, 1);
//var_dump($order_filled);

$ship_to = array (

  'addressInformation' =>
    array (
      'shippingAddress' =>
        array (
          'region' => 'Wien',
          'region_id' => 95,
          'country_id' => 'AT',
          'street' =>'aaa',
            array (
              0 => 'Fillgradergasse 12-14/1a',
            ),
          'company' => 'acolono GmbH',
          'telephone' => '1111111',
          'postcode' => '1060',
          'city' => 'Vienna',
          'firstname' => 'Martin',
          'lastname' => 'Testman',
          'email' => 'kamlesh@jivainfotech.com',
          'prefix' => 'address_',
          'region_code' => 'W',
          'sameAsBilling' => 1,
        ),
      'billingAddress' =>
        array (
          'region' => 'Wien',
          'region_id' => 95,
          'country_id' => 'AT',
          'street' =>
            array (
              0 => 'Fillgradergasse 12-14/1a',
            ),
          'company' => 'acolono GmbH',
          'telephone' => '1111111',
          'postcode' => '1060',
          'city' => 'Vienna',
          'firstname' => 'Martin',
          'lastname' => 'Testman',
          'email' => 'testman@acolono.com',
          'prefix' => 'address_',
          'region_code' => 'W',
        ),
      'shipping_method_code' => 'flatrate',
      'shipping_carrier_code' => 'flatrate',
    ),
);

$order_shipment = $magento->setShipping($cart, $ship_to);
// var_dump($order_shipment);

//$payment = $magento->getPaymentMethods($cart);
//var_dump($payment);

$ordered = $magento->placeOrder($cart, 'cashondelivery');
echo "\nordered:\n";
var_dump($ordered)

;
```

Can any one help me on this problem ?
Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably give some code example how do you call the API

Answer (score 0):

All seems good with your code I have tried it and it's working .Check with your
instance custom modules and access token.

Comment: Need more information ...What is entity field in order of magento2?.

Comment: @KamleshJha you find your answer for sales order entity here [link]http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162801/how-to-create-a-simple-product-using-soap-api-in-magento2