# How to create a simple product using SOAP api in magento2

Tags: product, api, soap, magento-2.1.4

Here I have tried but I getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Sender] %fieldName is a required field.

```php
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');
$token = '6ge34qaj7ugklona2in8fmmig93qmblx';
$wsdlUrl = 'http://localhost/magento214/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1';
$opts = ['http'=> ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " .$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient  = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
      $productData = array(
        'sku'               => 'ZZ-TEST',
        'name'              => 'testproduct',
        'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
        'type_id'           => 'simple',
        'price'             => 45,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ['3'] ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Simple Description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple  Short Description' ),
            )
    );
      $productData = json_encode(array('product' => $productData));
     //  print_r($productData);exit;
$result = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1save($productData);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: By posting only array of product data it is showing me Invalid product data: %1 changes i made is '$result = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1save(array('product' => $productData));' and removed the previous line'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below works.

Tested on `Magento 2.1.4`.

The error you received:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Sender] %fieldName is
>   a required field.

was due to `json_encode`ing `$productData`. Magento simply could not find `product` fieldName.

You don't need to `json_encode` things and parameters should be `typeId` and `attributeSetId`.

```
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');
$token = 'qdst8d40dfdfdfdfd43r3ererenx26f';
$wsdlUrl = 'http://m214.domain.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1';
$opts = ['http'=> ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " .$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient  = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
  $productData = array(
    'sku'               => 'ZZ-TEST',
    'name'              => 'testproduct',
    'visibility'        => 4,
    'typeId'           => 'simple',
    'price'             => 45,
    'status'            => 1,
    'attributeSetId'  => '4',
    'weight'            => 1,
);
$result = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1save(array('product' => $productData));
var_dump($result);
```

**Disclaimer**: I could not make `description`, `category_ids` and `short_description` work though.

Comment: thanks @konstantin, I have removed the json_encode and tried this earlier but not checked with typeId & attributeSetId.It worked thnx.

Comment: very welcome sir!

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov How do I send 'qty'=>'20.0000' please?

Comment: How do I update the price and stocks of the products using the values in another database? @KonstantinGerasimov